# grails default app fails to start (grails 3.1.5)

Tags: grails

I'm just trying out grails and it's already failing with this error:

```
grails> create-app
| Application created at /path/hello
| Initializing application. Please wait...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.553 secs
grails> run-app
| Running application...
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

[stack trace]            

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValuePreJava7 with modifiers "public"

[more stack trace]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValuePreJava7 with modifiers "public"
(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:36)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I think there's some cache that's blocked up somewhere, but I've tried "grails clean" and "gradle clean" and "clean-all" but no luck there.

I'm really not doing anything more than what you see in the dump above- I create a new app and try to run it. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problems withs jvm 1.7. 
Try to use jvm 1.8. Tested at 1.8.0_25. 
Or you can try to run app using "grails run-app" command from app folder (works with jvm 1.7.0_80).

Comment: Hi - thanks for replying. In the end I deleted my .grails directory and I could make some progress after that.